# Jmeter Download csv file is showing 0 Bytes

Tags: json, performance, jmeter, listener, jmeter-plugins

API call for download a file which is csv is giving good repsonse in Tree listeners. I have save the downloaded file using save response to a file listener using prefix with name.csv.

But on chcing in bin folder of jemter the same csv seems to be 0 bytes. whereas in tree listeners i can see repsone.

what should i do to get the same data in csv file too.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w646H.png)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you're looking at the wrong file. If you want the result to be saved as `CTCbreakup.csv` you need to use the following configuration of the [Save Responses to a file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file) listener:

[image]

Default configuration will give you something like `CTCBreakup.csv1.octet-stream`

More information: [JMeter Performance Testing: Upload and Download Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-testing)

Comment: I am actually geting now the  downloaded file in HTML format even by giving .csv extension in prefix. Need to get the proper CSV file. which Devloper are doing using some javascript in front end to convert the json to csv file again. How can i do the same to get the proper csv file download